# adehabitatHS Selection ratios (+/- IC) plot in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2

I am using the adehabitatHS package to estimate the resource selection of a species. I want to plot the results using the ggplot2 package, but I don't know how to do it.

In te table "Manly's Selection ratios for design I", the values of the confidence intervals for the Selection ratios (+/- CI) are not shown
Initially, I manually calculated the Selection ratios (+/- CI) using the following formula: " SE.WI * abs(qnorm(alpha / length * (WI)))", but the results are different.

These are the data:

```
disponibilidad.semillas.blennidus <- c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2) 
semillas.consumidas.blennidus <- c(4,14,12,28,5) 
names(semillas.consumidas.blennidus)  <- c("Chenopodium quinoae",
                                           "Lepidium chichicara",
                                           "Malvastrum",
                                           "Senecio comunis",
                                           "Urocarpidum")
names(disponibilidad.semillas.blennidus) <- names(semillas.consumidas.blennidus)
```

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer.** It looks like your formula should be `SE.WI * abs(qnorm(alpha / length (WI)))`.

**The long answer.** I'm not familiar with the `adehabitatHS` package or resource selection studies. However, here's what I've understood from looking at the vignette for the package, accessed via `??adehabitatHS`.

You have data on 5 species of seeds used by a species of beetle in the genus Blennidus. All 5 species were equally available, so

`disponibilidad.semillas.blennidus <- c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2)`

and the beetle(s) used the following numbers of seeds of each species

`semillas.consumidas.blennidus <- c(4,14,12,28,5)`.

Then, you use the package `adehabitatHS` to calculate the resource selection ratios $w_i$ for design I data types. Calling `?widesI` in R gives a short description of the functions. To calculate resource selection, I'm assuming you defined `u` as the used seed counts and `a` as the available seed proportions. We then look at the summary

`wi.blennidus <- widesI(u = semillas.consumidas.blennidus, a = disponibilidad) wi.blennidus`

The summary table is described on page 32-34 of the vignette for the package. The table doesn't include confidence intervals but the package includes a function to plot the summary statistics. We plot the selectivity measure and confidence intervals with the following line (it's the first of the 3 plots)

`plot(x=wi.blennidus, errbar="CI")`

[image: resource selection figure from package]

Is this the figure that you are trying to reproduce in ggplot? If so, here's how you can figure out how the package calculates the confidence intervals. When you call `plot(x=wi.blennidus)` you are actually calling `plot.wi` in the background. You can examine the code for this function by typing `?plot.wi`. Scroll through and find the line to calculate z-score for confidence intervals at the desired threshold value (default alpha is 0.5):

`z.score <- abs(qnorm(x$alpha/length(x$wi))))`

And get the standard errors

`sewi <- x$se.wi`

To calculate confidence intervals for each species, we multiply the z-score and standard error:

`ci <- sewi * abs(qnorm(wi.blennidus$alpha/length(wi.blennidus$wi)))`.

We can then place the data in a data frame, order the species by their estimated selection ratio, and plot in ggplot. Here's the full code and figure.

```
# load packages
library(adehabitatHS)
library(dplyr) # for working with data frame
library(ggplot2) # for plotting

# data
disponibilidad.semillas.blennidus <- c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2)
semillas.consumidas.blennidus <- c(4,14,12,28,5)
names(semillas.consumidas.blennidus)  <- c("Chenopodium quinoae",
                                           "Lepidium chichicara",
                                           "Malvastrum",
                                           "Senecio comunis",
                                           "Urocarpidum")
names(disponibilidad.semillas.blennidus) <- names(semillas.consumidas.blennidus)

# calculate resource selectivity
wi.blennidus <- widesI(u = semillas.consumidas.blennidus, a = disponibilidad, alpha = 0.05)

# calculate z score based on threshold level
z.score <- abs(qnorm(wi.blennidus$alpha/length(wi.blennidus$wi)))

# multiply z score and standard error to get confidence interval
ci = sewi*z.score

# get estimated selection ratio
selection.ratio = wi.blennidus$wi

# place data in data frame for plotting
df = data.frame(selection.ratio = selection.ratio,
                selection.ratio.ci = ci,
                species = names(semillas.consumidas.blennidus))

# rearrange species factors by selection ratio
df <- df %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(selection.ratio)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(species=factor(species, levels=species))

# plot
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=species,y=selection.ratio,
                    ymin = selection.ratio-selection.ratio.ci,
                    ymax=selection.ratio+selection.ratio.ci)) +
  geom_pointrange() +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Species") +
  ylab("Selection ratios (+/- CI)")
```

[image: resource selection figure from ggplot]